# openCV Python camera calibration - crop and ROI

Tags: python, opencv, roi, lenses

I am using OpenCV-Python to correct lense distortion on pictures. I use the script given in this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#calibration).

If I apply the script on the picture provided by the author of the script, its working.

However, if I use my own picture, I can either get a ROI = (0,0,0,0) or a ROI such that the crop is not good.

I don't understand why. I don't know what to do :./

- Is there a specific way to take picture of the chessboard?

  - chessboard should be close/far from the camera?
  - I should take several pictures?
  - the camera should not move?
- Should I define the size of my chessboard square somewhere?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

M.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally it works now, and I'll answer my own question ^^

- Is there a specific way to take picture of the chessboard?

  - chessboard should be close/far from the camera?

    --> The chessboard should be close to the picture edges.
  - I should take several pictures?

    --> At least 10 if not 20
  - the camera should not move?

    --> It could move
- Should I define the size of my chessboard square somewhere?

  --> Apparently not, but it is better if the chessboard is not a square (eg 9x9 little square, it is better to have a 4x8 chessboard).

  --> Still, I don't know the answer of this question

Remarkable things I noticed:

- The pictures should have same orientation (landscape)
- The cropped picture does not have necessarily the same dimension than the original one

Thank you myself :D